# Create one attribute "stats" in JSON from XML containing multiple attributes "stats" in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML input with elements that have a number of attributes named "stats".

I'd like to create just one attribute element "stats" for each of the existing attributes and put it in JSON as one key.

Input:

```
<STATS>
    <CODE>Apple</CODE><COUNT>4</COUNT>
</STATS>
<STATS>
    <CODE>Orange</CODE><COUNT>1876</COUNT>
</STATS>
<STATS>
    <CODE>Kiwi</CODE><COUNT>9</COUNT>
</STATS>
```

Output:

```
"STATS":{
    "Apple":4,
    "Orange":1876,
    "Kiwi": 9
}
```

UPDATE:
I've tried this XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">{
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object or Element Property-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" :<xsl:call-template name="Properties">
        <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="'Yes'"> </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Array Element -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object Properties -->
<xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:param name="parent"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>            
        <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$parent='Yes'"> <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>":"<xsl:value-of  select="."/>"</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>           
        </xsl:when>                
        <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of  select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>{
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            }</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Attribute Property -->
<xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this doesn't work, it seems. It is giving me the following output:

```
    "STATS" :{

    "CODE" :"Apple",
    "COUNT" :"4"
            },
    "STATS" :{

    "CODE" :"Orange",
    "COUNT" :"1876"
            },
    "STATS" :{

    "CODE" :"Kiwi",
    "COUNT" :"9"
            }
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: In your input, `STATS` are *elements*, not *attributes*. And you are missing a root element. Also, I see no connection whatsoever between your XSLT and the XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've updated the xsl code I tried. But it still doesn't seem to be giving the right output. What's the right way for this? I've posted the output and the xsl I tried.

Comment: The problem is that your transformation needs this input `<STATS><Apple>4</Apple><Orange>1876</Orange><Kiwi>9</Kiwi></STATS>` to get `{"STATS" :{"Apple" :"4","Orange" :"1876","Kiwi" :"9"}}`

Comment: @Alejandro what may be the right xslt for the given input? I tried something like this. `<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="/STATS">
<xsl:value-of select="CODE"/>
<xsl:value-of select="COUNT"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: @KarthikGullapalli That was a good attempt. See the other answers to grasp how to  deal with delimiters.

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro I've looked into other posts here and figured out how to achieve this. Looks like XML to JSON using XSL for different types of transformations needs different logic.

Answer (score 1):

Given a **well-formed (!)** input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <STATS>
        <CODE>Apple</CODE>
        <COUNT>4</COUNT>
    </STATS>
    <STATS>
        <CODE>Orange</CODE>
        <COUNT>1876</COUNT>
    </STATS>
    <STATS>
        <CODE>Kiwi</CODE>
        <COUNT>9</COUNT>
    </STATS>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text>"STATS":{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="STATS">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="CODE"/>
        <xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="COUNT"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

wil return:

**Result**

```
"STATS":{"Apple":4,"Orange":1876,"Kiwi":9}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand how xsl works from your code. And this helped me in solving the problem I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to achieve this JSON output is the following XSLT-1.0 code. It does assume that your input XML is wrapped in an element named `root` to make it *well-formed*.

So the input XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <STATS>
        <CODE>Apple</CODE><COUNT>4</COUNT>
    </STATS>
    <STATS>
        <CODE>Orange</CODE><COUNT>1876</COUNT>
    </STATS>
    <STATS>
        <CODE>Kiwi</CODE><COUNT>9</COUNT>
    </STATS>
</root>
```

The XSLT-1.0 file satisfying your needs looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text>STATS: {&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="STATS" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- STATS elements -->
<xsl:template match="STATS">
    <xsl:text>  "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="CODE"/><xsl:text>": </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="COUNT"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
STATS: {
  "Apple": 4,
  "Orange": 1876,
  "Kiwi": 9
}
```